# Is it possible to filter a matrix by a tagged array?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a 10 dimensional matrix with many, many columns (in the hundreds of thousands). I have however, implemented a tag based on the day of an experiment and a condition

So my original matrix looks something like

```
0.1 0.25 0.64 0.15 0.1 0.96 0.01 0.05....
                  .
                  .
                  . 
                  .
0.2 0.3  0.049 0   0.3 0.71  0.4 0.45....
```

I was able to implement a tag for the day and experiment type so my matrix looks like

```
0.1 0.25 0.64 0.15 0.1 0.96 0.01 0.05....
                  .
                  .
                  . 
                  .
0.2 0.3  0.049 0   0.3 0.71  0.4 0.45....
 1   1    1    1   2    2     2   2
 1   1    2    2   2    3     3   3
```

The top row represents a day, and the bottom row represents a condition. Is there anyway to "filter" this matrix, call it A, by day and condition in MATLAB? So for example, if I want the day 1 condition 2 "mini-matrix", I can get

```
 0.64   0.15
      .
      .
      . 
 0.049    0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by accessing only the columns matching a certain value in your day or condition rows.

For example, say your input matrix is `A`, and that the entries in the third row `A(3,:)` are the days, and the entries in the fourth row `A(4,:)` are the conditions.

Then `A(:, A(3,:) == 2)` will give you the subset of columns in A where the day is 2.

And `A(:, A(3,:) == 2 & A(4,:) == 1)` will give you the columns where the day is 2 and the condition is 1.